# how to find index from object array where two condition matche in swift5

Tags: arrays, swift, object

I want to find the index from array of object on the base of two condition

I want swift code or any reference for this

Comment: `firstIndex(where:)` should do the trick, you write the test needed in the closure.

Answer (score -1):

It's fairy straight forward. You use [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/firstindex(where:)) and either the `&&` or `||` operators depending on whether you want both conditions to be true, or either oe of the two.

For example:

```
func cond1(_ item: SomeElementType) -> Bool { ... }
func cond2(_ item: SomeElementType) -> Bool { ... }

let index1 = arrayOfSomeElementType.firstIndex(where: { cond1($0) && cond2($0) }) // First index where both cond1 and cond2 apply

let index2 = arrayOfSomeElementType.firstIndex(where: { cond1($0) || cond2($0) }) // First index where either cond1 or cond2 apply
```

A more concrete example

```
func cond1<T: BinaryInteger>(item: T) -> Bool { item.isMultiple(of: 2) }
func cond2<T: BinaryInteger>(item: T) -> Bool { item.isMultiple(of: 3) }

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let index1 = array.firstIndex(where: { cond1(item: $0) && cond2(item: $0) }) 

let index2 = array.firstIndex(where: { cond1(item: $0) || cond2(item: $0) })

print(index1 ?? -1)  // 5
print(index2 ?? -1)  // 1
```

Of course, you don't have to create separate functions for the conditions. The last example can be done like this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let index1 = array.firstIndex(where: { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) && $0.isMultiple(of: 3) }) 

let index2 = array.firstIndex(where: { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) || $0.isMultiple(of: 3) })
```